# How to extract sub-directories from the URL using 'REGEXP_EXTRACT' in Data Studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to extract the product name from the URL between the 2 slashes using `REGEXP_EXTRACT`. For example, I want to extraxt `ace-5` from the URLs below:

> www.abc.com/products/phones/ace-5/
>   www.abc.com/products/phones/ace-5/?cid=dm66363&bid
>   www.abc.com/products/phones/ace-5/?fbclid=iwar30dpnmmpwppnla7
>   www.abc.com/products/phones/ace-5/?et_cid=em_367029&et_rid=130

I have a RegEx to extract the Domain Name but it is not something I'm actually looking for. Below is the RegEx:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(page,'^[^.]+.([^.]+)')
```

It gives the following result: `abc`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the product name would always be the fixed fourth path element, we can try:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(page, '(?:[^\/]+\/){3}([^\/]+).*')
```

or, if the above would not work:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(page, '[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+).*')
```

Here is a demo for the above:

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, Tim!

This solution worked but partially. For an instance if we have the below URL, this REGEX would extract 'buy' out of it.

www.abc.com/products/phones/ace-5/buy/

Which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Then you need to articulate to us a fixed rule for how we can find the product name.  If its position be completely arbitrary, then there may not be such a rule.

Comment: The product name will be at the same position in each of the URLs. Some of the URLs might have more sub directories, even then the order or the position of the product name won't be changed. Even in the following URL product name is at same position: www.abc.com/products/phones/ace-5/buy/. But the REGEX is showing the string which is coming before the last "/" and that shouldn't happen. What I'm expecting from this REGEX is to show only "ace-5" even when the URL has more sub-directories.

Comment: I got it.  Try the updated answer.  If it gives you trouble, please also try this: `^[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)`

Comment: Updated REGEX worked as expected when tested on regex101.com. However, when I used it in Data Studio as a calculated field, it showed following error- Syntax error: Unexpected "^".

Comment: Remove the `^` anchor.  My guess is that `REGEXP_EXTRACT` automatically matches the entire input.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have the Same Page with my GDS, but I tried to recreate with my set of data source i.e pages from the google analytics.

Use may use the below which will get you all the records after two slash as per your requirement.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,'[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)')
```

You need to create a calculated column with this formula, once you have created this calculated column you might need to add an additional filter to remove those with the `null` value.

example Page: "/products/phones/ace-5/"
The Calculated Column value will be "ace-5"

Just make sure this regex will only give you the extracted word after phones/, if you do not have any record after that it will give you null in return.

Comment: The above Regex is returning 'phones' from the URLs and not the product names following it.

Comment: Can you please share the actual value of the Page Dimension

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you meant by that. Do you mean the full URL of the page? If yes, below are the sample URLs: 

www.abc.com/products/phones/ace-5/
www.abc.com/products/phones/ace-5/buy/
www.abc.com/products/phones/ace-5/?cid=dm66363&bid

The REGEX should extract 'ace-5' from the above mentioned URLs.

Comment: Not the full URL of the page, but what you get the value on Google Analytics for Page Dimension: e.g: /products/phones/ace-5/

Answer (score 0):

The [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below does the trick, extracting all characters after the 3rd `/` till the next instance of `/`:

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page, "^(?:[^/]+/){3}([^/]+)")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/6fa6f86f-8603-4c6b-91f7-65c0fa7597e2) and a GIF to elaborate

[image]

Comment: Having answers that "do the trick" but do not include an explanation only drive users to depend on StackOverflow volunteers.  Every answer should include an educational explanation for the benefit of the OP and thousands of future researchers.